# Resize buttons in phpBB

Tags: php, css, phpbb, phpbb3

So I have a module and I'm trying to resize the buttons used in the module so they fit a larger image. Also how can I downscale an image to fit specific button dimensions?
Here's the css code I use for the buttons. The buttons' images are imported through thanks-icon and removethanks-icon. This is the image with the icons that are imported atm:[image: IMAGE1]. I want to replace those with my owns buttons which are: [image: this] for upvote and [image: img3] for downvote (rescaled so they fit a button like the "Locked" button for posts.

```
dl.thanks {
    min-height: 35px;
    background-position: 10px 50%;      /* Position of folder icon */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

dl.thanks dt {
    padding-left: 45px;                 /* Space for folder icon */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 5px 95%;       /* Position of topic icon */
    width: 45%;
}

dd.lastpostthanks {
    width: auto;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
dd.lastpostthanks span {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
/* List in forum description */
dl.thanks dt ol,
dl.thanks dt ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

dl.thanks dt li {
    display: list-item;
    list-style-type: inherit;
}
li.header dl.thanks {
    min-height: 0;
}

li.header dl.thanks dt {
    /* Tweak for headers alignment when folder icon used */
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

/* Forum list column styles */
dl.thanks {
    min-height: 35px;
    background-position: 10px 50%;      /* Position of folder icon */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

dl.thanks dt {
    padding-left: 45px;                 /* Space for folder icon */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 5px 95%;       /* Position of topic icon */
}

/* Icon images
---------------------------------------- */
.icon-thanks            { background-image: url("./images/icon_thanks.gif"); background-repeat: no-repeat; }
.icon-thanks_toplist    { background-image: url("./images/icon_thanks_toplist.gif"); background-repeat: no-repeat; }


/* Profile & navigation icons */
.thanks-icon:before
{
    width: 60px;
     background-position: -3px -1px;
     background-image: url("./images/icons_button_likes.png");
}
//.thanks-icon:hover:before{ background-position: -3px -19px; }

.removethanks-icon:before
{
    background-position: -18px -2px;
    background-image: url("./images/icons_button_likes.png");

}
.removethanks-icon:hover:before {background-position: -18px -20px; }

.thanks_reput_image_back
{
    background:  url(../../../images/rating/reput_star_back.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.thanks_reput_image
{
    background:  url(../../../images/rating/reput_star_gold.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I edited it again to be more explicit. Sorry for the initial post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `background-size:cover;` to scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area

Comment: but how can you downscale my images to fit a specific button instead? or just need to do it right in Photoshop and use what you said instead?

Comment: If you want to fit the image change `cover` to `contain` (Scale the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area)